# openvpn: make it restart if process fails

Tags: services, systemd

I'm testing openvpn to restart if it fails for whatever reason.

I edited the file /lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service (with vi straight, just in case) and set the Type to simple, added Restart=always and RestartSec=60. Then ran **systemctl daemon-reload** and then started my openvpn service (systemctl start openvpn@blahconfig.service) which makes it start. Then I forcefully kill openvpn process with kill and it remains as *dead*, no intent to restart it.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing two files:

```
/lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service
/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service
```

The first is the "service" file that you edited. The second is the "template unit" file that was actually invoked when you started your service.

Second, you are editing files in `/lib` which are intended to be read-only and may be overwritten by an upgrade.

You should use the [Drop-in Unit](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-systemd-drop-in-units.html) pattern to override just the changes you need, storing files under `/etc/systemd/system` instead.